# How to render custom value with MUI DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datepicker

I want to write a React TS component returning a MUI DatePicker but whenever I choose a new date I want a custom component (called `<Badge>`) to appear in the value field.

I have already done it with MUI Select:

```
return (
    <div css={styles.wrapper}>
      <MaterialSelect
        value={value || ''}
        renderValue={(selected) => {
          if (selected === '' && placeholder) {
            return <span css={styles.placeholder}>{placeholder}</span>;
          }
          return (
            <Badge
              customText={placeholder}
            />
          );
        }}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem value={option.value} key={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </MaterialSelect>
    </div>
  );
};
```

However in MUIDatePicker (from @mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker) I'm not able to use renderValue and the only way of editing the fields I found is using slots and slotprops. I tried different ways like:

```
return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
      <MUIDatePicker
        label={label}
        value={dateValue}
        open={open}
        onClose={closePicker}
        onOpen={openPicker}
        onChange={handleChange}
        css={styles.root}
        views={yearOnly ? ['year'] : ['year', 'day']}
        slotProps={{
          textField: {
            value: <Badge type={BadgeType.DELAYED} customText="Test" />,
          },
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
```

But that actually changes the value of the field and I want to keep value as dateValue. There's also no renderValue in slots, slotprops or any other place I could find. Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't solve my problem but for now I use startAdornment to render a component and set the value of textfield to display: none. Component now returns:

```
 <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
      <MUIDatePicker
        value={dateValue}
        open={open}
        onClose={closePicker}
        onOpen={openPicker}
        onChange={handleChange}
        css={styles.root}
        views={yearOnly ? ['year'] : ['year', 'day']}
        slotProps={{
          textField: {
            placeholder,
            error,
            InputProps: {
              startAdornment: value && (
                <Badge
                  type={BadgeType.IN_PROGRESS}
                  customText={`${placeholder}: ${value}`}
                  customStyles={styles.filterBadge}
                />
              ),
            },
          },
        }}
      />
      {!isFilterField && <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>}
    </LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to show the week of whatever date is picked (sat-sunday) and ended up using @Axels as inspiration.

I didn't see how @Axel's solution hide the built-in textfield, so I ended up going in a similar direction but I just hide the date picker textfield completely and use a separate TextField in its place where clicking on it will open the picker.

Then just set the Textfield value based on the selected date (which for my use case will always be sunday of the given week:

```
const WeekPicker = props => {
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState(moment());
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const [displayWeek, setDisplayWeek] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const startOfWeek = date.clone().startOf('week');
    const endOfWeek = date.clone().endOf('week');
    setDisplayWeek(
      `${startOfWeek.format('MM/DD/YYYY')} - ${endOfWeek.format('MM/DD/YYYY')}`,
    );
  }, [date]);

  return (
    <Box>
      <DatePicker
        value={date}
        open={open}
        onClose={() => {
          setOpen(false);
        }}
        onChange={newDate => setDate(newDate.endOf('week'))}
        slotProps={{
          textField: {
            sx: { maxWidth: 0 },
            InputProps: { endAdornment: null },
          },
        }}
      />
      <TextField
        value={displayWeek}
        onClick={() => {
          setOpen(true);
        }}
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: <CalendarTodayIcon />,
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Result:
[image: Result]